# ListBox ItemTemplate CurrentItem is null

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the background color of a datatemplate generated stackpanel in a ListBox, via a button that is also generated in the same stackpanel that I want to change the color of. All using the FindVisualChild method. However I don't even reach that part of the code since my CurrentItem has the Value of null, even though my Items are populated. I have been googling like a madman and haven't found anything similar to this problem.

Please Help.

The XAML:

```
<DataTemplate
                    DataType="{x:Type data:Roulette}">
                    <StackPanel
                        x:Name="ARHiglight"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        >
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="{x:Bind QueueNumber}" 
                            FontSize="64" 
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource NeutraFace}" 
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            >
                            <TextBlock.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Resources>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="ARSeatButton"
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI Emoji"
                            Content="&#x2714;"
                            FontSize="25"
                            Foreground="Green"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Margin="50,0,2,0"
                            Click="ARSeatbutton_Click"                            >
                            <Button.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Resources>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            x:Name="ARDeleteButton"
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI Emoji"
                            Content="&#x1F5D1;"
                            FontSize="25"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Margin="10,0,2,0"
                            Click="ARDeleteButton_Click"
                           >
                            <Button.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Resources>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

The code-behind:

```
 private void ARSeatbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBoxItem = (ListBox)RouletteList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(RouletteList.Items.CurrentItem);
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
        DataTemplate roulette = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)roulette.FindName("ARHighlight", contentPresenter);


        stackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
    }
```

Comment: Consider using MVVM. Bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand in the view model item class. The command would change a Brush property of the item to which the StackPanel's Background is bound.

Comment: Besides that, is this about UWP? There is `x:Bind` in your XAML.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your answer. This is WPF, with a Nuget package to use X:Bind. Probably not best practice. This is my first WPF project and I have worked in UWP before hence using x:Bind was a convinience for me

Comment: Better use ordinary Bindings and drop that package. Get used to the "WPF way".

Comment: You do not need to add tags to question titles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190

Comment: are you sure your current item is null? i have noticed that WPF initialises itself with null and then runs the bindings if you are tracing the initialisation you could be seeing null when the issue is that the binding hasn't run yes, especially as you are using a 3rd party tool on your binding

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your answer. I used a different approach to solve this issue. Not using this at all. Since this was a small project I did for myself. Thanks for your time, and I will try to do this approach in the future 